# Communication between nginx & Aws API Gateway

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have a use case in which i have to call AWS API Gateway from an nginx hosted on EC2. 
Since API Gateway uses SSL by default, i was trying to set nginx upstream with SSL but was not able to configure it successfully.

i get the error below :

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: yy.yy.yy.yy, server: api-gateway.cloud, request: "GET /devint/echo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://zz.zz.zz.zz:443/devint/echo", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx:8000"
```

How should i approach fixing it.

Comment: Looks like Nginx is trying to use SSL v3.

Comment: I think you can mark this answered by @Angelo R.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am also going down this rabbit hole. CloudFront requires some additional headers to be sent before it will accept the request.

This seems to be in-line with what AWS is expecting:

```
set $upstream_endpoint ROOT_API_GATEWAY_FQDN;
resolver DNS_RESOLVER_IP;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
proxy_pass         https://$upstream_endpoint;
proxy_buffering off;
```

The part that resolves your particular problem is setting `proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2` and `proxy_ssl_server_name on`.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway uses a cloudfront distribution, and supports custom domain names using [SNI (Server Name Indication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

nginx added for SNI since version 1.7. You can find more info about this here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_server_name

Set `proxy_ssl_server_name directive on` in your reverse proxy configuration.